# LaTeX/Markdown in notebook

Tags: notebooks, formatting

I know that there is the wonderful `MaTeX`, which is a third party package, but is there a way to duplicate the Jupyter notebook functionality, where one can have markdown cells (complete with MathJax typeset equations)? This seems about 10 years overdue :)

Comment: MathJax is a JavaScript library that produces output meant for browsers (SVG, web fonts.) I'm not sure that they could support MathJax without becoming a browser.

Comment: @C.E. I don't really care if it is MathJax or not, as long as it renders :)